# How do I run other python separate inside of kivy program

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Coming from Arduino to python I am use to everything running in a loop more or less.

I am trying to understand how python interacts with kivy.

I understand that in order to make a segment of code run over and over I need a while statement for example. However if I use code that loops before it gets to the kivy code it will never get to the kivy code. But if I make a loop after the kivy code it will not run till I close the program.

I have google around and I see examples of simple projects of python/kivy projects that all the code pertains to the UI glue logic to make it actually do something. But I have not seen anything show python code running independent of the kivy project.

In other words if I made a project in Arduino I would have a main loop and I could call out to functions and then return from them. However I don't understand what is the best way to do this with kivy/python.

The sample code I have posted below is not a loop however I would expect it to run everything in one go. But It will run the first print statements and then when I close the app the last print statement will run.

I understand that loops are not recommended with object oriented programing, this is just a simple example as reference of what I'm use to.

For those that will say I don't understand what your asking and what are you trying to do or ask?

I am trying to ask where do I put python code that dose not pertain immediately to the kivy code but needs to run in loops or whatever while kivy is running. So that I can make things happen on the python side while not blocking kivy.

Dose this require multiple python programs? And leave the kivy program by itself almost like a .kv file.

Or dose it require everything to be put in classes?

Thanks for any clarification, best practices or examples.

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button

print("test")

class FirstKivy(App):

    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Test text")

print("test2")

FirstKivy().run()

print("test3")
```

Comment: The line `FirstKivy().run()` runs the kivy `App` main loop. and does not return until that loops exits (the `App` exits). Kivy is event based, so almost everything in a Kivy `App` is run as a result of some event. If you are trying to run code that is long running (like another loop), then you need to use another `Thread` or another `Process` see [concurrency](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/concurrency.html).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add Threading to your code

```py
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button

import threading

print("test")

class FirstKivy(App):

    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Test text")

print("test2")

def run():
    FirstKivy().run()

def print_stuff(): 
    print("test3")

kivy_thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
print_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_stuff)

kivy_thread.start()
print_thread.start()
```